Can $\int e^{-|x|^a}\,dx$ where 0<a<1 be given an analytical solution?
As the title suggests. Are there any solutions to solving this integral analytically or by using a power series? $\int e^{-|x|^a}dx$ where $0<a<1$?
Any help, suggestions, or leads given are greatly appreciated. Also are there any functions that you could suggest which could approximate this integral such that $f(x) \leq \int e^{-|x|^a}\,dx \leq g(x)$?

I suppose you’re integrating over the whole real line. By symmetry, this is twice the integral over $(0,\infty)$. Now make the change of variables $t=x^a$. It seems like you should be able to reduce this to the integral definition of the Gamma function. Off the top of my head, $2\cdot \frac{1}{a}\Gamma(1/a)$ or something similar.

It's possible when $1/a$ is an integer.

Ohhh it looks like you want the indefinite integral (I wrote the above because you said you wanted to approximate the integral so I assumed you meant a definite one). But in general you won’t have a nice formula for this; it will involve the incomplete Gamma function.

I also think the gamma functions the way, but can't quite find the solution.

A definite integral solution over $(0, x(t))$ would also be helpful.

Ok then just apply what I said in the first comment.

Let $x^a=t$, therefore, we have:
$$x=t^{\frac1a}$$
$$dx=\frac1a t^{\frac{1-a}{a}}dt$$
Thus the integral leads to:
$$\int_0^{x(t)} \frac 1a e^{-t}t^{\frac{1-a}{a}}dt$$
For an easier approach, consider the exponent to be $m$, then the integral takes the form of:
$$\int_0^{x(t)} (m+1) e^{-t}t^mdt$$
$$=(m+1)\int_0^{x(t)}  e^{-t}t^mdt$$
Since the definite limits are not from $0$ to $\infty$, we cannot use the gamma function $\Gamma$ here. Moreover, we shall go through reduction method to find an analytical solution.
Just consider the integral here:
$$I_m=\int e^{-t} t^m dt$$
We can go through by integration by parts and obtain:
$$I_m=e^{-t} t^m-\int e^{-t}mt^{m-1}dt=e^{-t}t^m-mI_{m-1}$$
And this recursive process goes on, until we find and reach $I_0$ which is:
$$I_0=\int e^{-x}dx=e^{-x}$$
This combined results gives a general formula of:
$$I_m=e^{-x}\left(x^m-mx^{m-1}+\frac{m(m-1)}{2!}x^{m-2}-...(-1)^m\right)$$
$$
I_m=e^{-x}\left(\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{(-1)^km!}{(m-k)!k!}x^{m-k}\right)
$$
Wrapping up, we have our total integral to be:
$$
(m+1)\int_0^{x(t)}  e^{-t}t^mdt=(m+1)\left[e^{-x}\left(\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{(-1)^km!}{(m-k)!k!}x^{m-k}\right)\right]_0^{x(t)}
$$
You better set the rest by yours. And hopefully, get a nicer solution.

Seems like it only works when $m$ is an integer.
